# SQL query with special conditions not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

please help me with my MySQL Query.

Basically I want to retrieve some users for a user-ranking-system. My project is based on a wordpress installation. But since my query is very specific, all wordpress methods and functions are useless. 
I try to describe my query in words:

"Give me all Users, who have a minimum of three posts which have a minumum rating of 4 for each post. Furthermore each of the users post needs to have a minimum of 5 ratings."

(The date-conditions below in the query are unimportant, work perfectly)

For storing data, posts are saved as usual in wp_posts (special post_type). The amount of ratings for each post is stored with a meta value (key=rating_count). Each rating is stored in the table "wp_rating" (id, post_id, rating, user_id).

My Query looks like this:

```
SELECT SUM(r.rating) AS rating,
p.post_author AS user_id,
COUNT(r.rating) AS rating_count
FROM wp_rating r 
INNER JOIN wp_posts p ON p.ID = r.post_id 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta meta ON meta.post_id = p.ID 
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' 
AND (meta.meta_key = 'expiration_date' 
AND meta.meta_value < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), 'Ymd'))
AND (meta.meta_key = 'rating_count' AND meta.meta_value > 4)
AND MONTH(p.post_date) = 03 
AND r.rating > 4 
GROUP BY p.post_author 
HAVING COUNT(p.ID) > 3 
ORDER BY SUM(r.rating) DESC
```

The problem is the following line:

```
AND (meta.meta_key = 'rating_count' AND meta.meta_value > 4)
```

I dont get any results after firing this query. (I checked all posts twice for enough ratings)

I hope my description is okay for finding a solution.

Kind Regards,
Robin :-)

PS: Please help, Im very confused :(

Answer (score 0):

At the same time column can be equal to one value `meta.meta_key = 'expiration_date'` or `meta.meta_key = 'rating_count'` how it is possible that at same time column can have these two values, i guess you have one to many relation between post and their meta you need another join to your `wp_postmeta` table to fullfill your second condition,and make sure you are comparing date to date type here `meta.meta_value` it smells like you have  text type of `meta.meta_value` column

```
SELECT SUM(r.rating) AS rating,
p.post_author AS user_id,
COUNT(r.rating) AS rating_count
FROM wp_rating r 
INNER JOIN wp_posts p ON p.ID = r.post_id 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta meta ON meta.post_id = p.ID 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta meta1 ON meta1.post_id = p.ID 
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' 
AND (meta.meta_key = 'expiration_date' 
AND meta.meta_value < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), 'Ymd'))
AND (meta1.meta_key = 'rating_count' AND meta1.meta_value > 4)
AND MONTH(p.post_date) = 03 
AND r.rating > 4 
GROUP BY p.post_author 
HAVING COUNT(p.ID) > 3 
ORDER BY SUM(r.rating) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess you helped me out of this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

i guess 'rating_count' you mean it the aliace you created before.

try that:

```
 AND (meta.meta_key = COUNT(r.rating) AND meta.meta_value > 4)
```